# Finding the cause of this endless loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am working on this program that is due shortly for class but cannot for the life of my figure out why I have an endless loop. This is my first coding class so this is all pretty new to me. I have figured out that the loop is coming from my "getLocation" method and I think something is wrong with the way I am trying to count my "location" variable, but like I said I am not sure. We have just started using multiple classes and private constructors and it is really throwing me off. I will take any help I can get. Thanks!

```
public int getLocation(){
    while (location <= 250) {

    location = 5;
    location++;                     //endless loop here
    System.out.println("test");
    }

    return location;
}
```

Comment: I've cut down your code to a [mcve]. You posted way too much code that just obscured the issue.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the suggestion! I will keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 3):

```
while (location <= 250) {

location = 5;
location++;                     //endless loop here
System.out.println("test");
}
```

`location` can never exceed 250 in this loop. After executing the loop body, its value is always 6, because you set it to 5 and add 1.

So, provided `location <= 250` when it reaches this loop, it will never stop.

Move the `location = 5;` outside the loop body (or just delete it).

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getLocation(){
    while (location <= 250) {
         location = 5;  // every loop this equals 5
         location++;                
     }
    return location;
}
```

You set location equal to 5 every loop.  Move this to before the `while()` so that you only set it once then increment once per loop.

```
public int getLocation(){
    location = 5;            //  this equals 5 initially
    while (location <= 250) {
         location++;         // this will now increment appropriately
     }
    return location;
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but why not just `return location = 251;` and forgo the loop? It's not really clear this is what OP intends.

Comment: @AndyTurner No it's not clear.  But he said it's his first programming class.  Some things you just learn with time.

Comment: Sorry: `if (location <= 250) location = 251; return location;`.

Answer (score -1):

You can NOT see if you are blind.  I use lots of print statements so that I can see what the program is doing.  If you do NOT know what the problem is, you do NOT know where to put the print statements.  So put lots of print statements so you can see.

Comment: Seriously? 'Put lots of print statements', while possibly helpful, is certainly not an answer. And more so not THE answer here. 'Attach a debugger' if nothing else, but not this

Comment: Make full use of any debugging features that are available. If no debugging features are available, then a well placed print statement would  be informative.  In my case, I would prefer to be using Code::Blocks which has debugging features.   However, I can not get it to work.  Code::Blocks can not find my Arduino libraries.  Any help would be appreciated.